# Angular 2 Typescript: Get service not finding my RESTFUL API

Tags: rest, angular, asp.net-web-api, typescript

I am trying to do a get on my service and get a 404 error, it's definitly there and works as I have tested it using PostMan an API testing tool.

Here is my code:

```
const headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Authorization','eyJ0eg'); 

return this.http.get('http://myserver:8090/lookup/nationalities', { headers: headers } )
.map((data: Response) => data.json())
.catch(this.handleError);
```

My error in Chrome dev tools:

```
Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}
```

In Post Man I simply fill in the headers section with an Authorization key and add the value in then press send. All works fine. However in my code it does not.
Does anyone know what I am missing or what could be causing this issue?

Comment: How about CORS, although it doesn't give 404 but would be worth checking.

Comment: I am having the same issue, so it would be helpful, if you shared your solution in case you found out what was causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, the problem was with the actual API, we fixed that and it worked fine :)